# I have just made a 2TB CentOS vm but the disk isn't available

Tags: centos, disk-usage

Yesterday I made a fresh VM with 2.0Tb of disk.

When I do `df -H`, this is what I get:

```
[root@datastore ~]# df -H
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_datastore -lv_root
                       53G   19G   32G  37% /
tmpfs                 519M  234k  519M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             500M   30M  444M   7% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_datastore -lv_home
                      2.2T  116M  2.0T   1% /home
```

For some reason, Linux is saying there is only 32Gb available out of 53Gb, shown by (and  this is the bad bit) when I go to this directory it has almost no space.

```
[root@datastore ~]# df -kH /var/www/html/datastore/data
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_pfsowncloud-lv_root
                       53G   19G   32G  37% /
```

How do I get the CentOS server to stop putting `/var/www/html` on `/dev/mapper/vg_pfsowncloud-lv_root` and start it using `/dev/mapper/vg_datastore -lv_home`? In other words, how do I make it so that when I type `[root@datastore ~]# df -kH /var/www/html/datastore/data` I get

```
[root@datastore ~]# df -kH /var/www/html/datastore/data
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_datastore -lv_home
                      2.2T  116M  2.0T   1% /home
```

Comment: VM? This is rather a LV?

Comment: erm kind of a mix of bad grammar and back acronyms? So pretty hard to decipher but if I read you right: No, it was not an issue due to the host misreporting the size of the logical volume to the guest, because vmware suffers from that misreporting issue, hyper-v does not. And this is Hyper-V baremetal host. Also, it is a fresh Virtual Machine, how Cent 0S 6.6 sets out 2TB by default - which is ridiculously stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can create a `/home/html` and tell apache/nginx/httpd whoever to use it.
   I cant elaborate, this depend on you web server.
2. you can make a symbolic link from `/var/www` to `/home/www`

   ```
   cd /var
   mv www www.old
   mkdir /home/www
   ln -s /home/www /var/www
   ```
3. If you have no use for `/home`, umount it, and mount `vg_datastore-lv_home` on `/var/www`

(you may try to `umount /home` first, it might succeed )

- edit `/etc/fstab` to comment line with /home
- reboot
- edit /etc/fstab, replace /home by /var/www (in filesystem column)

  ```
  mount /var/www
  ```

(this will "hide" everything under /var/www, you may use 2. mv and mkdir commands above to retrieve what was under /var/www)

4. of course you can replace `/var/www` above by `/var/www/html/datastore/data`

Comment: (Mr U&L SE, we can't mix <ol> and <pre> ??? )

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, maybe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown ?

Comment: @Gilles thx, didn't know 8 spaces trick !!